# Detecting which font should be used

Tags: x11, fonts, locale

I am wondering how a system knows which font should be used for an output. 
E.g. recently I was setting up my Debian for Japanese support, so first: installed Japanese locale, then a package with fonts, rebooted - and whola! - the system is in Japanese now. But I would not get that without installing the specific fonts. How does the system know that a particular font should be used for particular language/locale? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The piece of software responsible for font selection in Linux is [Fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig). It examines the properties of each font as well as its own configuration to determine which ones have glyphs that cover specific languages partially or fully and substitutes them as appropriate.